# logstash-input-heroku running as a service on ubuntu (logstash 5.2.1)

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, logstash, systemd

I'm trying to run logstash on an aws ec2 instance running ubuntu 16.04 using systemd. I've installed heroku toolbelt on the machine. Running the pipeline normally (via bin/logstash.bat) works fine and events are ingested (however after a few minutes a get a "Request timed out" error and the pipeline stops, which is a separate question).

But when I try to run the service on systemd I get errors, not sure if the two types of errors are related. The first is an SSL error:

> **Error: no cipher match (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)**
>
> [2017-02-15T13:08:44,037][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin
>   had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.   Plugin:
>   "xxxxxx",
>   codec=>"^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}
>   %{WORD}\[\w+(\.\d+)?\]:(\s{3,}| \})", what=>"previous",
>   id=>"032c3b317ae49982945ec7e8fbf11224be98f237-3", enable_metric=>true,
>   negate=>false, charset=>"UTF-8", multiline_tag=>"multiline",
>   max_lines=>500, max_bytes=>10485760>,
>   id=>"032c3b317ae49982945ec7e8fbf11224be98f237-4", enable_metric=>true>

The second is that the heroku toolbelt seems to be prompting for credentials:

> Feb 15 13:08:43 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[4402]: Enter your Heroku
>   credentials.
>
> Feb 15 13:08:43 ip-10-0-1-216 logstash[4402]: Email:
>   Password (typing will be hidden):

My logstash configuration:

```
input {
    heroku {
        app => "xxx-1"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{WORD}\[\w+(\.\d+)?\]:(\s{3,}| \})"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
    heroku {
        app => "xxx-2"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{WORD}\[\w+(\.\d+)?\]:(\s{3,}| \})"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
    heroku {
        app => "xxx-3"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{WORD}\[\w+(\.\d+)?\]:(\s{3,}| \})"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
    heroku {
        app => "xxx-4"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{WORD}\[\w+(\.\d+)?\]:(\s{3,}| \})"
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}

filter {
  grok {
    break_on_match => true
    patterns_dir => ["./grok_patterns"]
    match => { "message" => [
        "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:heroku_source}\[%{DYNO:dyno}\]: %{LEVEL:level}: HTTP %{OPT_NOT_SPACE_COMMA:organization}, %{OPT_NOT_COMMA:user}, %{OPT_NOT_COMMA:device}, %{WORD:method} %{ENDPOINT:endpoint}%{QUERY:query} \[%{INT:responseCode:int}\].*? \(p%{INT:nodeProcess:int}\) \(%{INT:responseTime:int}ms\).*$",
        "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:heroku}\[%{WORD:component}\]: at=\w+ method=%{WORD:method} path=\"%{ENDPOINT:endpoint}\??%{QUERY:query}\" .*?fwd=\"%{IP:site_ip}\" dyno=%{DYNO:dyno} .*?service=%{INT:responseTime:int}ms status=%{INT:responseCode:int} bytes=%{INT:sizeBytes:int}.*?$",
        "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:heroku_source}\[%{DYNO:dyno}\]: (?<data>.*)"
    ] }
    add_field => { "endpoint_template" => "%{endpoint}" }
  }
  mutate {
    gsub => ["endpoint_template", "[0-9a-f]{24}", "ID"]
    add_field => { "type" => "heroku" }
  }
  if ![heroku_source] {
    geoip {
        source => "site_ip"
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => { "heroku_source" => "heroku" }
    }
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "aws-es-endpoint:443" ]
        ssl => true        
    }
}
```

(I'm sure it could be improved)

I've tried running the service as root but the result is the same. Just to clarify, this works:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/
```

While this does not:

```
sudo systemctl start logstash
```

This is a clean install of logstash 5.2.1 following the [procedures on elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html). Systemd is also run according to [their procedures](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash.html), so that it executes the same command as I execute manually. `cat logstash.service` output:

```
[Unit]
Description=logstash

[Service]
Type=simple
User=logstash
Group=logstash
# Load env vars from /etc/default/ and /etc/sysconfig/ if they exist.
# Prefixing the path with '-' makes it try to load, but if the file doesn't
# exist, it continues onward.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/logstash
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/logstash
ExecStart=/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/
Nice=19
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(result is the same when I comment out the user and group above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, turns out the problem was that systemd was not seeing the heroku credentials. I asked a [similar question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883625/ssl-error-only-when-running-on-systemd/883662#883662). The solution was to add the ubuntu home directory to the logstash service so it would access the credentials. Accomplished by editing the `logstash.service` file in */etc/systemd/system* and setting `Environment="Home=/home/ubuntu"` there.

Example of final logstash.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=logstash

[Service]
Type=simple
User=logstash
Group=root
# Load env vars from /etc/default/ and /etc/sysconfig/ if they exist.
# Prefixing the path with '-' makes it try to load, but if the file doesn't
# exist, it continues onward.
Environment="HOME=/home/ubuntu"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/logstash
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/logstash
ExecStart=/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/
Nice=19
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```